# Create an image showing max intensities in a set of images?

Tags: image-processing, image

I would like to use a set of two images with the same color scheme (`img1` and `img2`) to produce a new image (`img3`) in which each pixel corresponds to the "higher pixel color value" of `img1` and `img2`.

Imagine objects (e.g. disks) in `img1` have the color `col1`:

```
col1= ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.5]
```

In `img2` the disks are at different positions (partly overlapping with `img1`), they should have the color `col2`:

```
col2= ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.2]
```

For the resulting image `img3` we should check if objects in `img1` and `img2` overlap there. If so, then the pixel gets the color `col1` (because `0.5 > 0.2`).

If at a pixel only one of the images has an object, then color remains the same. A scheme with only three colors might look like this:

- blue AND red --> red
- blue AND background --> blue
- background AND red --> red

Comment: Higher color picture? On what color space?

Comment: I was nor precise, see above ..

Comment: Let me ask more clearly: If `img1` is `RGB[.5,.1,.3]` and `img2` is `RGB[.4,.2,.4]`... what do you want as result?

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic What you want is in general not possible, because the mapping `value -> {r,g,b}` which you use to create `img1` and `img2` has (in general) no inverse. What you can do is to calculate the max *before* you turned your gray values into colors, but this is what bill has already shown you in his answer.

Comment: @halirutan Have you seen my answer? I think it still has some problem, but looks good overall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice Problem.

Perhaps something like:

```
f[x_] := List @@ (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][x]);
s = Table[(f@x) -> x, {x, 0, 1, .001}];
k = Nearest@s;
```

Usage:

```
c = DensityPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> None, 
               PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> 100] & /@ {x, y};
m = Map[k, (List @@@ ImageData@#), {2}] & /@ c;
GraphicsRow[Join[c, {Image@Map[f, MapThread[Max, m, 2], {2}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Although I think there is still a small problem in the interpolation in the middle of the max zones.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use ImageApply. For example, if img1 and img2 are two images of the same size, then

```
ImageApply[Max, {img1, img2}]
```

takes the max of each channel.

Comment: see changes above ...

Comment: Define the map/function you want to use and place it in ImageApply instead of Max.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is it so easy?